# Is there a good way to unserialize individual array elements in PHP?

Tags: php, serialization

Is there a way to use PHP to unserialize individual array members?

Example - array of serialized objects

```
//$array
Array
(
    [0] => O:21:"Calc\Calc":22:{s:3:"qok";...
    [1] => O:21:"Calc\Calc":22:{s:3:"qok";...
    [2] => O:21:"Calc\Calc":22:{s:3:"qok";...
)
```

What I want is to transform it into an array of objects.   For example, say I want to

1. unserialize them like I want
2. convert result into JSON

Is there was perhaps a way to do it like so:

```
$resultingJSON = '[' . implode(',', MAGIC_UNSERIALIZE_EACH($selections)). ']';
```

Comment: `array_map('unserialize', $arr)`? `json_encode`?

Comment: Do note that there are serious security issues with [serialization](https://www.evonide.com/how-we-broke-php-hacked-pornhub-and-earned-20000-dollar/).

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - rather than making such a blanket statement, it might be worth indicating that the security issues relate to unserializing data received directly from user input

Comment: @Chibu, that was an interesting read.. thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker It was not a blanket statement though, just a bit vague, but with a link for clarification.